# Can I handle FCM notification message without data field in background state?

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, message

I have a problem that to handle FCM notification message.

I want to handle notification message without data fields.

So I've implement firebasemessagingservice in my project, but onMessageReceived function did not triggered.

Is it possible? Can I handle none data fields notification message in background state?

Comment: No IT is not possible. Eventually not possible without data payloads if you want to show the notification when your app is in the background.

Comment: @Muhaiminurabir Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `onMessageReceived` only gets triggered in the background when you have a data payload, see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) for details.

If you only have a notification field, it will land in the system tray and be handled by system, if you still want to handle the notification yourself, change the message payload to data and just include the related notification information and push out a notification yourself, for more details, see [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says you can do this with setBackgroundMessageHandler() which goes in the firebase-messaging-sw.js file.

I have never done it, but that is what the documentations says.